# Fill NA cells accross rasters

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a raster stack (spatraster) with 129 layers. The layers are monthly images from Landsat-8. A lot of cells contain NA values due to clouds. My goal is to fill these NA pixels with some sort of interpolation or some other method. What I have tried so far:

1. Linear interpolation
   I used the `approximate` function from the `terra` package (with both `linear` and `constant` arguments)
2. I used the `cover` function where I created an annual composite and I replaced the NA values of each layer with the cell values from the annual raster.

The results are shown below (for a layer containing a lot of NAs):
[image: results]

As you can see the results are from optimal. For comparison, below is the image of the annual raster:
[image: annual raster]

It is clear that in the annual raster the spatial details (e.g., road network) can be seen easily, compared to the results in the first image.

I'd like to ask what other method(s) I could use that might help me fill the NA cells.

The code:

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.7.71

wd <- "path/"

# annual raster
r_const <- rast(paste0(wd, "path/annual.tif"))

# low pixel coverage raster
low <- rast(paste0(wd, "low.tif"))
plot(low)

# dense pixel coverage raster is a raster in the raster stack with dense pixel coverage
dense <- rast(paste0(wd, "dense.tif"))
plot(dense)

s <- c(low, dense)
names(s) <- c("low", "dense")
plot(s)

# approximate
x <- approximate(s)
plot(x)

# cover
x1 <- cover(low, r_const, values = NA)
plot(x1)
```

I understand that it is recommended to create a reproducible example, which I tried on my PC, but by creating a raster with random values (i.e., no spatial details like roads) and some NAs here and there it is difficult to see which method better preserves those spatial details. For this reason, I share 3 rasters:

1. a low pixel density raster
2. a dense pixel density raster
3. the annual composite.

You can download them from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18b48jZoW6c7kjsRkpP6abwRW51u4mRyM?usp=sharing).

The ultimate goal is to use monthly data as covariates in a downscaling process of monthly coarse resolution data.

Windows 11, R 4.3.2, RStudio 2023.12.1 Build 402.

Comment: You can do a temporal imputation using loess or some other method (nowadays LSTM is popular one among ML methods for temporal imputation). I don't recommend you to impute using a single date, unless you have trained a CNN model for filling patches beforehand (like https://github.com/appelmar/STpconv, but with a single date)

Comment: I was hoping for a more _basic_ solution, if possible. Like for example the `approximate` function.

Comment: Well, you wrote "I used approximate" and then your question is "I'd like to ask what other method(s) I could use". Well, since I couldn't understand, I can't help

Comment: We can't answer "how" until we know "why". Any imputation technique is going to have an effect on further analysis, and some imputation methods may mean you cant meaningfully do the further analysis. If you just want it to look like reasonable values for appearances sake or as test data, then that would be a useful thing to tell us.

Comment: I edited my question and added the final goal of using the monthly data (downscaling process). I hope this helps.